# Suggestions on what to do with an old Power Mac G4?

Tags: mac, power-mac

So I've had an old Power Mac G4 sitting around collecting dust.

Realistically, is there anything I can do to salvage this old, run down machine?

My thoughts were to turn it into a backup server but again realistically how much power will that run? I assume its a power hog.

I'm mainly, dare I say it, a Windows users but use my iMac just as much as my Windows PC.

Salvage for parts? Ideas? Just trash it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea, you could try to run a server on it for back-up purposes or website hosting maybe? I don't know if you're interested in that part at all.. If it's a big power waste, you'd better get rid of it and buy a replacement instead of wasting the cash on power :)

Trashing it is the last option left IMO.